# insert strtok results into char* (increased dynamic)

Tags: c, strtok

I'm loosing my mind.
I want to split string (char* text) with spaces and insert the string results into array and return this array.
I have the following method in C

```
char *read_command(char *text)
{
    int index=0;
    char *res=NULL;
    char *command= (char*)malloc(strlen(text)+1);
    strcpy(command, text);
    char *tok = strtok(command, " ");

    while(tok!=NULL && index ==0)
    {
        res = (char*)realloc(res, sizeof(char)*(index+1));
        char *dup = (char*)malloc(strlen(tok)+1);
        strcpy(dup, tok);
        res[index++] = dup; //Error here
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    res[index++]='\0';

    return res;
}
```

from main method

```
char *input="read A B C";
char *command = read_command(input);
```

Thank you

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` ? , `&& index ==0` ??, `res[index++]='\0';` ???

Comment: So just to make it clear: do you want to concatenate the tokens? Or do you want to place them in an array of strings? Because for the latter, a `char *` is not good enough. Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: I'm realy new in C. if I send "read A B CCC" I want an array of strings so [0]=A [1]=B [2]=CCC thank you

Comment: Why are you using malloc+strcpy instead of `strdup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong type to calculate the size in this call:

```
res = realloc(res, sizeof(char)*(index+1));
```

You need to use `char*`, not `char`, with `sizeof`, like this:

```
res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*)*(index+1));
```

Since your code returns a pointer to C strings (represented as `char*`) the return type should be `char**`.

You need to remove the `index == 0` condition from the `while` loop, otherwise it wouldn't go past the initial iteration.

This assignment

```
res[index++]='\0';
```

should be

```
res[index++]=NULL;
```

You also need to call `free(command)` before returning the results to the caller. Finally, you should not cast results of `malloc` in C.

Here is your code after the fixes above:

```
char **read_command(char *text) {
    int index=0;
    char **res=NULL;
    char *command= malloc(strlen(text)+1);
    strcpy(command, text);
    char *tok = strtok(command, " ");
    while(tok!=NULL) {
        res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*)*(index+1));
        char *dup = malloc(strlen(tok)+1);
        strcpy(dup, tok);
        res[index++] = dup;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    // Need space to store the "terminating" NULL
    // Thanks, BLUEPIXY, for pointing this out.
    res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*)*(index+1));
    res[index]=NULL;
    free(command);
    return res;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Qm2zpt)

Comment: Thank you very much it's working. Can you please explain why I shouldn't cast the malloc, realloc result? In the course I'm studing now I have been told that I must cast the malloc result?

Comment: @user3132295 Casting `malloc` is required in C++, but in C it is optional. Here is [a link to an answer explaining the reasons why it shouldn't be done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/335858).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **read_command(const char *text){
    int index=0;
    char **res=NULL;
    char *command= malloc(strlen(text)+1);
    strcpy(command, text+strspn(text, " \t\n"));//strspn for skip space from top
    char *tok = strtok(command, " ");

    res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*)*(index+1));
    while(tok!=NULL){
        res[index++] = tok;
        res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*)*(index+1));
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    res[index++]=NULL;

    return res;
}

int main(void){
    char *input="read A B C";
    char **command = read_command(input);
    int i;
    for(i=0;command[i]!=NULL;++i){
        printf("s[%d]=%s\n", i, command[i]);
    }
    free(command[0]);//for free command of read_command
    free(command);//for free res of read_command,,
    return 0;
}
```