# Using malloc() and realloc() to store strings in an Array

Tags: c, malloc, clang, realloc

getWordsArray() gets a pointer to a char array - the input.

Im trying to split that input and store each word in a char array. And eventually return that char array.

```
   char *getWordsArray(char *input)
    {
        char *token;
        char *search = " ,";
        char *splited, *temp;
        int counter=0;
        splited = malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
        token = strtok (input,search);
        while (token != NULL ) {
            printf("%s\n",token);
            token = strtok (NULL,search);
          //  splited[counter] = *token;  //aliasing ?
            strcpy(&splited[counter] , token);
            temp= realloc(splited,(counter+1)*sizeof(token));
            if (temp !=NULL) {
                splited = temp;
            } else{
                free(splited);
                printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
                return 0 ;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        printf("list is: %s\n",splited);
        return splited;
    }
```

It seems like it works since it prints correctly. 
But i get:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

on

```
strcpy(&splited[counter] , token);
```

Anyone can point me out whats wrong ?

Comment: The `sizeof(token)` part looks really suspicious: You're multiplying by the size of a pointer, yet your dynamic array is not an array of pointers...

Comment: The variable `splited` is a *single string* not an array of strings.

Comment: sizeof(token)??? this value is always 4. did you mean strlen(token) by any chance?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20825387/971127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function return type is all wrong; it needs to be `char **`, not just `char *`.  The allocation strategy in the function is wrong, too, therefore.  You need to allocate an array of `char *` as well as an array of `char` for each component word that is stored in the array of `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the string, e.g. on `strcpy(&splited[counter] , token);`, it is very likely, that it's too long for the destination. That is because you do not allocate an array of strings but an array of `char`.